# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo una situación un tanto rara, o creo que no entiendo que es lo que está pasando del porque no entra al `if` estoy usando la var `this.searchParams.data` donde sucede 3 situaciones

1. No hay nada
2. Aparece price_desc
3. Aparece price_asc

Entonces estoy usando el indexOf por el simple motivo que usamos ES5

Pero viene como objeto

```
{sortBy: "price_asc"}
```

Pero por más que intente que cuando no está definida o no existe no entra al `if` para mostrar los productos...

```
    this.searchParams = window.getSearch();

    this.searchSortBy = Object.values(this.searchParams.data)[0];

    console.log('-----------1-----------');
    console.log(typeof this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') == null);
    console.log('-----------2-----------');
    console.log(this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') === "undefined");
    console.log('-----------3-----------');
    console.log(typeof this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') == null);

    if (!this.searchParams.data.price && typeof this.searchSortBy.indexOf('price') == null) {
      this.getProducts();
    }
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Ya probaste String(this.searchSortBy).indexOf('price') == "-1"

Comment: Marco, intente colocando un `setTimeout` de 1- segundos,luego antes del if valide si `this.searchParams.data` es diferente de `null` o `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que tienes un mal concepto de como funcionan o como se usan ciertos métodos y funciones.

Para empezar

> typeof: retorna el tipo de la variable (operando) que estas
>   consultando

algunos ejemplos:

```
typeof undefined //retorna 'undefined'
typeof null //retorna 'object'
```

> indexOf: retorna el índice de la primera ocurrencia que encuentra y si
>   no lo encuentra retorna -1

ahora `indexOf` puede ser usado en Strings y Arrays y si lo usas en otro tipo de variables (dígase numbers, booleans) te arroja el siguiente error

> Uncaught TypeError: indexOf is not a function

ahora si nos vamos al error que te arroja a ti:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

esto básicamente significa que en algún lugar de tu código hiciste lo siguiente:

```
undefined.indexOf(...)
```

lo que significa que muy probablemente la expresión siguiente te esta dando undefined

```
this.searchSortBy // <--- esa variable no existe
```

**EDICIóN**

si nos vamos a donde esta el inicio del problema pues es en esta linea de código

```
this.searchSortBy = Object.values(this.searchParams.data)[0];
```

Para dejar claros la utilización de `Object.values` te arroja un error claro si haces lo siguiente:

```
// estas sentencias arrojan error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"
Object.values(null)
Object.values(undefined)
```

en vista y considerando que no te pasa ese error significa lo siguiente

```
this.searchParams.data // <- esta variable si existe
// pero es probable que sea un objeto vacío, es decir
this.searchParams.data = {};
// lo que haría que
Object.values(this.searchParams.data) 
// lo anterior retornaría un arreglo vacío []
// otra opción es que la propiedad data sea como lo siguiente
this.searchParams.data = { a: undefined, b: 10};
```

sea como sea tu problema es la variable
`this.searchParams.data`